# Pyspark find common pairs of rows with column values

Tags: pyspark

Pyspark noob here. I have a data set that looks like this (with thousands of different start and endIDs):

```
startID,  endID
1         1
1         2
1         3
2         3
1         1
...
```

And I need to **count** up all the times (rows) where the combinations of startID and endID occurred together and get something like this:

```
startID   endID  count
1         1      2
1         2      1
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.agg()` is not needed here. Simply:

`df.groupBy('startID', 'endID').count().show()`

Comment: Thanks Cena, that was simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

group by and count.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupBy('startID', 'endID').agg(count(lit(1)).alias('count'))
  .show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, I got TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: 1 of type <class 'int'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Comment: Then use `lit(1)`